# Path is undefined,

Tags: node.js, path

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

What could be the possible reason? I searched a lot, it is giving error for a particular function.

here`s the first line of the function that is being called

```
path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates');
```

Comment: p.s: path is already included in the file.

Comment: add some more details how you are setting path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `__dirname` is coming as `undefined`. `__dirname` only works for scripts. If you're trying to run it in `REPL` it won't work and i think you're doing that.

create a new file `test.js` and copy paste the line below in it

```
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates'));
```

and run it:

```
node test.js
```

Hope this helps